# Automatic Editing of a string to remove spaces C#

Tags: c#, string

When I copy a string from an excel data set into the text box, the string has HUGE spaces in between each item in the string.

I currently have `if (textBox1.Text.Contains(" ") == true)` to detect the spaces in the string.

What would I use to delete those spaces?

Bonus Question: I do still need one space inbetween each item in the string, how would I add that and still delete the massive spaces?

```
    private void radioGenerateScript_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hexData.Cells.Copy();
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox1.Paste();
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains(" ") == true)
        {


        }
    }

    private void radioWriteScript_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string waveForm = textBox1.Text;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:/Scripts/Test.us1", waveForm);

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove all kinds of whitespaces use:

```
textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"\s+", "");
```

`\s` matches all whitespaces (spaces, tabs and new lines).

Comment: You need to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Comment: Literally just did that as you sent this response :P.

Answer (score 4):

```
textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, " +", " ");
```

It seems that you have tabs as separators, so the following is better (as Alexei suggested):

```
textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"\s+", " ");
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. But one thing I noticed is when I open the text file I wrote to. The space can be blown away with one hit of delete. As if there is one massive character there.

Comment: +1. Perfect case to use regex. You can consider `\s+` if you need to include tabs (which seem to be the case @DeeWBee - "one massive character") and all other strange "whitespace" characters like non-breaking space.

Answer (score 3):

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "");
```

If you want to keep *some* spaces then use `Split` and `string.Join`

```
var words = textBox1.Text.Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

textBox1.Text = string.Join(" ", words);
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. But one thing I noticed is when I open the text file I wrote to. The space can be blown away with one hit of delete. As if there is one massive character there.